# Translating SAS code to R: Simulation and Dataframes

Tags: r, statistics

I am working with this SAS code.

```
data a;
do i=1 to 10000000;
x = 12 + 2.5*rannor(0);
y = 15000 + 2500*x + 5000*rannor(0);
output;
end;
```

I am having a hard time in my attempt to write a suitable R code that can replicate (or rather be similar) to what I've done above.

All that I've been able to do was this:

```
set.seed(0)
x = 12 +2.5*rnorm(1)
y = 1500+ 250*x+ 500*rnorm(1)
```

...but I think the SAS program actually generates 10000000 x's and y's that have values based on their equations above, so I assume a dataframe is involved.

Anyone used R or/and SAS before? Any ideas as to how I can do something similar to the SAS code?

Comment: You don't need a data.frame to have two vectors of length 10000000.

Answer (score 2):

```
set.seed(0)
n = 10000000

library(dplyr)

data_frame(x = 12 + 2.5*rnorm(n), 
           y = 1500+ 250*x+ 500*rnorm(n) )
```

Comment: Oops. I'm used to data_frame, which allows self-reference during assignment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think an external package is needed here.

```
set.seed(0)
n <- 10000000
x <- 12+rnorm(n = n,mean = 0,sd = 1)*2.5
y <- 1500 + 250*x + 500*rnorm(n = n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
data <- cbind(x,y)
```

You just need to call `rnorm()` to include the `n` that you are seeking. I believe the above code will do that.